# IF AND Formula not outputting correctly

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Pretty new to excel but I am attempting to create a cell that includes the total of other cells only if they are under the right "name". This is the formula I am using, I have tried this in the "rules" section and just writing it in the cell, either way it doesn't work here is what I am trying to do:

if cell `B7` = `Poplast` and `F7` = `Unit 25` and `G7` contains the value `30`, add the value of `H7` onto the value that is already in `O8` and update the `O8` cell to its new value with `H7` added to it.

```
=IF(AND(B7="Poplast",F7="Unit 25",G7=30),O8+H7,O8)
```

There is no output to this cell even though all IF statements are correct?

[image]

Comment: In which cell does this formula live?

Comment: I have put this in the O8 cell

Comment: `O8` is referenced in the formula, this creates a circular reference.  Unless it is specifically allowed in the setting for Excel it will throw an error.

Comment: I'm afraid that just doesn't make any sense. `O8` is determined by this `if` formula. But within the `if` formula you are referring to the value that is in `O8` which is determined by this `if` formula. But within the `if` formula you are referring to the value that is in `O8` which is determined by this `if` formula. But within the `if` formula you are referring to the value that is in `O8` which is determined by this `if` formula. But within the `if` formula you are referring to the value that is in `O8` which is determined by this `if` formula. (it will either error or just spit out `0`).

Comment: Circular references for a workbook only you use and can maintain is more or less ok.  But if this is something others will be using it gets a little more complicated as they will also need to allow circular references and this setting is not workbook specific but for the entire Excel app.  VBA in a worksheet change event is much better solution to what you want to do.

Comment: So the if statement i want to take inn from several cells, so say b7, f7 and g7 (all one row) is true the value of that row h7 is 50, but then move down a row to b8, f8 so on and h8 is 50 then i was in the logical process of is the 7th row is true then O8 will equal 50, then if row 8 is true it will equal hundred as O8 already equals 50, and so forth if you get me?

Comment: Maybe a screen cap of sample data and corresponding result would be useful

Comment: I have provided a screen cap

Comment: I think you want SUMIFS(): `=SUMIFS(H:H,B:B,"Poplast",F:F,"Unit 25",G:G,30)`